# How do we authenticate using IDAnywhere Authentication?

Tags: java, api, authentication

What is IDAnywhere authentication? How can we use this authentication in Java to consume an API through its Url. The same url I can access now in browser with an username and password.

Example - [www.abc.com/products/id](http://www.abc.com/products/id) - gives me a json data as a response in the browser.

I want to get this done using and Id Anywhere auth. Please help.

Can anyone share any open resource to understand IDAnywhere authentication in detail.

Thanks in Advance!